# CakeEmail - How do i use it?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my controller i'm using a email function with the following code:

```
public function email($mail = null){

    $email = new CakeEmail('default');
    $email->config('default');

    $email->from(array('test@test.com' => 'testing'));
    $email->to('$mail');
    $email->subject('Approved');
    $email->send('Approved');
```

At the top i have

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller', 'CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

However, i receive the error Fatal error: Class 'CakeEmail' not found in.

I'm not sure where i have gone wrong. Can anybody please assist?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research. It was all in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html?highlight=cakeemail#CakeEmail

Comment: @luchomolina and now again for the 6th time upvoted

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to change your App::uses and separate the two:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

Comment: Can you please explain why they should be separated? It works, but it doesn't make sense. I'd like to know why :)

Comment: Because of the new way cake references the classes.

Comment: did the developers think it was sooo obvious? there is no reference in the docs..

Comment: this helps a lot, tnx :)

Comment: You're a genius. Now one minute silence for cakephp

Answer (score 5):

`App::uses()` does only allow two arguments: `$className` and `$location`. You passed 4 arguments, that's why CakeEmail is not loaded.

See http://api20.cakephp.org/class/app#method-Appuses and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::uses for more information

Answer (score 2):

the documentation is pretty clear about it:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html?highlight=cakeemail#CakeEmail

"First of all, you should ensure the class is loaded"

on a second look: your app::uses() is wrong. check out the way it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Email component in the controller

```
public $components = array('Email'); 

public function email(){
  $this->Email->to = 'yourmail@mail.com';  
  $this->Email->subject = 'Subject - ';   
  $this->Email->from = 'sender@mail.com';  
  $this->Email->send('message');
}
```

Comment: This is not advised; the [EmailComponent was deprecated in CakePHP 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/email.html).